# IDA. how can i install decompiler?

Tags: decompiling, decompiler, ida

I downloaded from official site(hex-rays) IDA, installed, everything works. I found needed for me function, pressed F5(hotkey for decompile so i would see C pseudocode), and got pop-up message:

***ida sorry you don't have any decompilers on windows***

Can't understand what's wrong and no info about such a message in google i found...

Here is the screen of message: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1iyz.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

D in IDA stands for *disassembler*. The free version of IDA does not contain the HexRays *decompiler* plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this "error" is just not professional pop-up from developers. Decompiler already installed, but it available only when you'll pay them.